# convert date DD-MMM-YYYY to YYYYMMDD in cobol

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to change the date format from `DD-MON-YYYY` to `YYYY/MM/DD` in **COBOL** and I was wondeing if that was possible.

I've been searching and I couldn't find any utilities or date function to change it.

What I've tried:

- Use `unstring` and converted **JAN** to `01`, **FEB** to `02` and so on.

Comment: Which compiler?  Which version of the compiler?  Which OS?

Comment: Concerning "standard-COBOL" you'd write your own `FUNCTION` because of the MON part. possibly similar as you did. For the returning value you can use the `FORMATTED-DATE` function, but there is no "standard" "any string in any language to month".

Answer (score 3):

COBOL suffers from a paucity of useful libraries and utilities.
Mostly COBOL programers just re-invent wheels and code stuff up themselves.

Something like (untested code!):----

```
01 OLD-DATE.
   05 OLD-DD    PIC XX.
   05 FILLER    PIC X.
   05 OLD-MON   PIC XXX.
   05 FILLER    PIC X.
   05 OLD-YEAR  PIC XXXX.
01 NEW-DATE.
   05 NEW-YEAR  PIC XXXX.
   05 FIRST-SLASH PIC X VALUE '/'.
   05 NEW-MM    PIC 99.
   05 SECOND-SLASH PIC X VALUE '/'.
   05 NEW-DD    PIC XX.
01 M-TAB.
   M      PIC XXX OCCURS 12.
01 M-VALS REDEFINES M-TAB VALUE 'JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC'.
01 M-X    PIC S9(8) COMP VALUE 0.

.......
  MOVE OLD-YEAR TO NEW-YEAR.
  PERFORM VARYING M-X FROM 1 TO 12
    IF OLD-MON = M(M-X)
        MOVE M-X TO NEW-MM
    END IF
 END PERFORM.
 MOVE OLD-DD TO NEW-DD.
```